# Shouldn't sample standard deviation DECREASE with increased sample size?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm doing an experiment comparing 10,000 rolls of 5 dice (those 5 rolls were then summed, so the population mean is 17.5) and dividing them into sets of ten with sample size N = 10. The same experiment is repeated except with 3000 rolls, but the sample size decreases to N = 3. Both experiments have 1000 samples, just with different sample sizes.

Now, I took the AVERAGE **sample** standard deviation for each experiment and to my great confusion, the experiment with the SMALLER sample size had a SMALLER average **sample** standard deviation than the experiment with the LARGER sample size. I thought this was a fluke and re-generated the random numbers only to find the same result.

In other words, this means that the **sample** standard deviation for each sample of N =3 is on average smaller than each sample of N = 10. 
How is this possible?

Intuitively, one would think that with a larger sample size the "spread" between values would be decreased because any individual improbable value would have less effect on the spread. Sort of like for the mean.
While for a smaller sample size, the variables would be less "controlled" and thus on average more spread out.

Is my intuition just wrong? And is this plain to see mathematically?

FOLLOW UP: I talked to my professor and he said that a weird phenomenon happens in statistics where **sample** standard deviations tend to be underestimations rather than overestimations of the population standard deviation. And that as sample size goes up, the **sample** standard deviation goes up because it becomes "more accurate."

Is this true? And why does that happen? Is there both an intuitive explanation as well as a mathematical proof?

Comment: Are you computing standard deviation or standard error?  Think about the standard deviation you would see with $N = 1$.  It would always be $0$.  It's smaller for lower $N$ because your average is always as close as possible to the center of the specific data (as opposed to the distribution).

Comment: @Ian: The standard deviation of the mean would be, but not the distribution of the quantity itself.

Comment: Further question: How much smaller is the $N = 3$ standard deviation.  Is it about $3/4$ of the $N = 10$ standard deviation?

Comment: Can you post the standard deviations you calculated?

Comment: Oh, yes, the standard deviation is normalized in just the right way that it will tend to oscillate around the population standard deviation as the sample size grows.

Comment: OP: My answer gives an explanation of this.  I don't think it's a weird phenomenon; it's just a result of using the (known) sample mean as the central tendency rather than the (unknown) population mean.  That's why sample standard deviations are often taken divided by $N-1$ rather than $N$.  (See my answer for more details.)

Answer (score 2):

Absent further clarification from the OP, here's what I think is happening:

Each sample consists of $N$ values drawn from a binomial distribution spanning the integer range $[5, 30]$.  *As a population*, the draws from this binomial distribution have mean $17.5$ and standard deviation about $3.82$ (I think, I have to double check this).

With a sample size of just $N$, however, the average of the sample is not generally $17.5$.  It will be some value which is overall closer to the sample than the population mean would be.  Hence, the standard deviation of that $N$-count sample, treated as a population, will systematically underestimate the standard deviation of the population.

For example, with $N = 3$, if you draw $12, 14, 16$, you have an average of $14$.  The standard deviation of the sample, treated as the population, is about $1.63$.  But the RMS distance from the actual population mean of $17.5$ is $6.69$.  The disparity arises from the sample average being closer to the data, overall, than the population mean.

The larger $N$ is, the smaller the expected disparity, and that's perhaps why you obtain a smaller standard deviation for $N = 3$ than you do for $N = 10$.

---

ETA: Dividing by $N-1$ instead of $N$ should produce an unbiased estimator for the population standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the choice of statistic you are calculating from your samples.  If you are taking the **sum** of the sample, then for a sample of size $N = 10$, you will observe sums ranging from a minimum of $10$ to a maximum of $60$.  But if your sample is of size $N = 3$, the range of the sum is only from $3$ to $18$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, ill re-clarify in my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues here related to how you calculate variance and standard deviation from a sample drawn from a population with unknown mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

1. An estimate of variance using $\frac{1}{n} \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$ is biased in the sense that its expectation is $\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$ rather than $\sigma^2$. This is caused by the $x_i$ tending on average to be closer to $\bar x$ than they are to $\mu$; if you had known $\mu$ then the larger $\frac{1}{n} \sum (x_i-\mu)^2$ would have been unbiased, but you did not.  This leads to Bessel's correction and so it is common to use $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$ as an unbiased estimator of variance.  (It is from a sample and in a sense also a random variable, so may still be too high or low, even though its expectation is $\sigma^2$.)
2. If you use $s^2$ to estimate the variance $\sigma^2$ then it is natural to use $\sqrt{s^2}$ to estimate the standard deviation $\sigma$.  But $\sqrt{\,}$ is not a linear function: it is concave, so $\mathbb E[\sqrt{s^2}] \lt \sqrt{\mathbb E[s^2]}=\sigma$.  For large $n$ you have $s^2$ tending to be a closer estimate of  $\sigma^2$ than it tends to be for small $n$, so this bias due to the shape of $\sqrt{\,}$ tends to be more substantial for values which are "more spread out", i.e. here for smaller $n$.

To illustrate this, a single fair six-sided die has expectation $\mu=\frac72=3.5$ and variance $\sigma^2=\frac{35}{12} \approx 2.916667$ and standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{35}{12}}\approx  1.707825$. The following table shows the expected values for $n$ dice for estimates using the average, the uncorrected estimate of variance, the Bessel-corrected estimate of variance, and the square-root of the  Bessel-corrected estimate of variance (though remember that each sample involves randomness and will give different values, some higher and some lower).

$$\begin{array}
 \,n & E\left[X_i\right] & E\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i-\bar X)^2\right] & E\left[\frac{1}{n-1} \sum (X_i-\bar X)^2\right]  & E\left[\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum (X_i-\bar X)^2}\right] \\
 1 & 3.5 & 0 & \frac00 & \frac00 \\
 2 & 3.5 & 1.458333 & 2.916667 & 1.374930 \\
 3 & 3.5 & 1.944444 & 2.916667 & 1.556217 \\
 4 & 3.5 & 2.187500 & 2.916667 & 1.618076 \\
 5 & 3.5 & 2.333333 & 2.916667 & 1.646405 \\
 6 & 3.5 & 2.430556 & 2.916667 & 1.661957 \\
 7 & 3.5 & 2.500000 & 2.916667 & 1.671558 \\
 8 & 3.5 & 2.552083 & 2.916667 & 1.677984 \\
 \lim\limits_{\to \infty} & 3.5 & 2.916667 & 2.916667 & 1.707825
\end{array} $$

and this illustrates your observation that "the experiment with the smaller sample size had a smaller average sample standard deviation than the experiment with the larger sample size".

Answer (score 0):

I believe Henry's answer gives the correct explanation. However, sometimes it helps to visualise the answer. Thus, here the plot of the (at first glance) counter-intuitive result
[image]

As claimed by the OP, if we calculate the standard deviation of the sets, we find an increasing function -- red dots. In contrast, if we first calculate the variance of the sets and then rescale the result (by taking the square root), we obtain an unordered function -- blue dots.

### What I have done:

1. Roll $n_{dice}=5$ random dices.
2. Calculate the sum of these five dices, and let's call the sum a single "set".
3. Generate $n_{set}$ "sets" and calculate their standard deviation (and variance). Store these results in two variables.
4. Repeat this $n_{sim}=10\,000$ times.
5. Calculate the average value of the two variables stored in step 3.
   The only parameter which we change in the procedure is the value of $n_{set}$ in step 3. We start with $n_{set}=3$ and increase it till $n_{set}=10$.

### R code, which generates the plot:

```
nDices = 5
nSets  = 3:10
nSim   = 10e3

data.std = vector(mode="numeric", length=nSim)
data.var = vector(mode="numeric", length=nSim)
Mean_SD  = vector(mode="numeric", length=length(nSets))
Mean_VAR = vector(mode="numeric", length=length(nSets))
for ( iSet in 1:length(nSets) ){
    nSet      = nSets[[iSet]]
    randomSum = vector(mode="numeric", length=nSet)
    for ( iSim in 1:nSim ){
        # A single "set" consists of nDices=5 dices. 
        # We first calculate the SUM of each "set", and then 
        # we calculate the standard deviation of nSet sets.
        randomSums = replicate(nSet, 
                               sum(sample(x=1:6, size=nDices, replace=TRUE)))
        data.std[[iSim]] = sd(randomSums)
        data.var[[iSim]] = var(randomSums)
    }
    # Finally, we calculate the average value of the standard deviation:
    Mean_SD[[iSet]]  = mean(data.std)
    Mean_VAR[[iSet]] = mean(data.var)
    #cat(paste0('nSet=', nSet, ' => E[Sd[randomSum]] = ', Mean_SD[[iSet]], '\n'))
}

## Plot
dataFrame = data.frame(nSets = c(nSets, nSets),
                       Mean_SD  = c(Mean_SD, sqrt(Mean_VAR)), 
                       grp = factor(rep(c('SD', 'sqrt(VAR)'), each=length(nSets))))
library(ggplot2)
gg = ggplot(dataFrame, aes(x=nSets, y=Mean_SD, col=grp)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.4) + 
    xlab('Number of averages sets')
print(gg)
```